# Staining an ipe deck

Tags: deck, hardwood, stain

So, I’m installing an ipe deck in the coming weeks.  I will stain with a basic UV protector.

I’ve never stained this much square footage before.  My (dumb) question is how do you wipe off excess stain?  The deck is about 20x20.. how do you get to the middle to wipe?  I assume I shouldn’t walk on the deck for a day or two.

Is it basically a rag on a stick?  I don’t have arms that are 10 feet long - I can’t reach the middle.

For some reason, I can’t wrap my head around this…

Comment: Don't paint yourself into a corner. work part of the deck at a time that you can reach. IPE is a great product for a deck, congrats on that choice. I know product recommendations are OT here, but I've had great luck with Penofin on IPE.   Oil based finishes are pretty forgiving when applied. Just do it part by part, it'll be fine.

Comment: Exterior stains are not wiping stains. You apply it and leave it to dry without wiping.

Comment: i can't believe someone would buy ironwood just to turn around and stain it. better hope it stains evenly, or else that's a costly mistake...

Comment: Gotta stain it with UV or it will be silver by next year.  

Ipe UV oil.